# Are ACM SSL certificates tied to a Hosted Zone or just the domain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, dns, aws-cloudformation, amazon-route53

I have been searching for answers for these three questions, so far have not got a concrete answer:-

1. Are ACM SSL certificates tied to a Hosted Zone or just the domain?
2. Can we replace the existing Hosted Zones with templated hosted zones without interrupting services?
3. Can Hosted Zones be managed using CloudFormation?

Comment: "so far have not got a concrete answer:" Which you won't get there as your question is offtopic on a website devoted to programming questions.

Comment: I thought StackOverflow is about tech..because tags are surly available for all the services..and not just programming languages

Comment: SO is for programming questions, please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  Not all "tech" questions are programming questions. And no, bad previous off-topic questions do not suddently make others on-topic, and same for tags.

Comment: I think my question is on point with reference to below two points-
software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

Comment: Certificates are not software tools. Otherwise everyone using them is a software developer, which means anyone using a browser, so that would be a bit large...

Comment: This question is not about certificates only..it is more about AWS services related to route 53, and ACM. 
Cool I get your point

Comment: I don't thing AWS services, Route53 or ACM are software tools per se, they are at best DevOps tools but then yes you can argue that DevOps has Dev. Anyway, personnally I think your question to be far more ontopic on [sf].

Answer (score 1):

1. Just the domain. You don't even need to use Route53 to use ACM.
2. Probably? There may be some interruption in the DNS resolution depending on how you roll out this change. As with anything like this, you should have a separate test environment to verify your rollout will work as expected before performing the changes in production.
3. See [the official CloudFormation documenation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-route53-hostedzone.html). I suggest reviewing the documentation in the future when you have questions about what AWS services are supported by CloudFormation instead of asking about each one on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thank you for the reply,
Maybe I was not clear about my third question. I saw aws documentation regarding route53 but was confused between working of AWS::Route53::HostedZone and recordset.. which one is used when.

Comment: A hosted zone is a domain. A record set is a single DNS entry inside a hosted zone.